# Why does my QLineEdit .text() returns an empty string

Tags: python, pyqt5

First of all, I have already read some queries of the same topic but nothing of relevance in my case. Here is a bit of snippets of my code:

```
class MyClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         self.wid_dict = {"wid1": (0, 1), "wid2": (1,1)}
         self.create()

    def create(self):
         for wid_name, value in self.wid_dict.items():
             widget = QLineEdit()
             widget.FinishedEditting.connect(partial(self.slots, widget.text()))

    def slots(self, text):
        print(text)
```

When I write an input in the widget and tabbed to the next widget, the result would only print an empty string. Am I doing wrong?

P.S. I have removed a chunk of my codes here as I'm typing it in a mobile phone.

Comment: `widget = QLineEdit(self); widget.editingFinished.connect(self.slots); ... def slots(self): print(self.sender().text())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>If you consider that your publication is not the best that you can do then it is better that you take more time, for example the code you provide is not the best since there are many errors</sup>

---

The problem is that you are getting the text a moment after creating the QLineEdit and it is clearly an empty text, a possible solution is to pass the widget

```py
from functools import partial
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class MyClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.wid_dict = {"wid1": (0, 1), "wid2": (1, 1)}
        self.create()

    def create(self):
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        for wid_name, value in self.wid_dict.items():
            widget = QLineEdit()
            widget.editingFinished.connect(partial(self.slots, widget))
            lay.addWidget(widget)

    def slots(self, widget):
        print(widget.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyClass()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another similar method is to use sender() in the slot which is a method that returns the QObject that emitted the signal:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class MyClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.wid_dict = {"wid1": (0, 1), "wid2": (1, 1)}
        self.create()

    def create(self):
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        for wid_name, value in self.wid_dict.items():
            widget = QLineEdit()
            widget.editingFinished.connect(self.slots)
            lay.addWidget(widget)

    def slots(self):
        widget = self.sender()
        print(widget.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyClass()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```